# Timer between activities

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I would like to have a single timer visible in more activity:

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="buttonclick"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentcontainer">

    </FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragment_chrono.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="00:00"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewchrono" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**activity2.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentcontainer2">

    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ChronoFragment cf;

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


         //create class with fragment
         cf= new ChronoFragment();


     }

     int numberclick=0;
     Intent i;

     public void buttonclick(View v){

        //add fragment to this class
             getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentcontainer, cf).commit();

        //pass class cf to another activity Activity2
             i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class);
             i.putExtra("Class",cf);
             startActivity(i);
     }

 }
```

**ChronoFragment.java:**

```
public class ChronoFragment extends Fragment implements Serializable{

    TextView chronot;
    private CountDownTimer Timer;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chrono, container, false);
        chronot= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewchrono);
        start();

        return v;
    }

    public void start(){
        Timer= new CountDownTimer(3600000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                chronot.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) -
                                TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                chronot.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }.start();
    }

}
```

**Activity2.java:**

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity{


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);


        Intent in=getIntent();
        ChronoFragment cf= (ChronoFragment) in.getSerializableExtra("Class");

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentcontainer2, cf).commit();


    }

}
```

When i click on the button in Mainactivity,he application, properly, brings me to the activity2  showing the same timer decreasing, if I go back the application still works properly, but if click again on the button in Mainactivity the app crashes with this error:

**Logcat** (beginning of crash):

```
01-19 22:15:17.982 23583-23583/com.timerbetweenactivities E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.timerbetweenactivities, PID: 23583
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.timerbetweenactivities.ChronoFragment)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1394)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1341)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:644)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1034)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:669)
    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7485)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2411)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1496)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:856)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4016)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3984)
    at com.timerbetweenactivities.MainActivity.buttonclick(MainActivity.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
 Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.timerbetweenactivities.ChronoFragment$1
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1344)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:959)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:360)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1054)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1389)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1341) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:644) 
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313) 
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1034) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:669) 
    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7485) 
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2411) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1496) 
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745) 
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75) 
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:856) 
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4016) 
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3984) 
    at com.timerbetweenactivities.MainActivity.buttonclick(MainActivity.java:37) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

**Thanks so much**

Answer (score 0):

You should not and can not to pass fragment instance via intent.

If you need to share timer progress between several activities, just pass progress via intent or store value in data base/shared preference/whatever in one activity and restore it in another.

Comment: maybe I'm wrong, but so I would not have a single timer, but one for activity,